# Reading from named pipe from background process

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a program that has a window and also outputs to stdout. I am reading the programs output and writing one line of that output to a pipe. This is done in the background while the program is still running. I send a command to the window and wait for my single line from grep. However, even though the program has already produced this text tail will not exit unitl I stop the program.

I want tail to return this one line as soon as it can so I can terminate the program with "\e" to the window.

```
bin/Prog | grep "TEXT" > /tmp/pipe2 &
xvkbd -window Window -text "2"
tail -n1 /tmp/pipe2 >> out.t
xvkbd -window Window -text "\e"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `tail` command doesn't know it has reached the last line of input until it gets EOF, and it won't get EOF until the `grep` terminates and closes its standard output.  Also, `grep` will buffer its output when the output device is not 'interactive', and a named pipe is not 'interactive', so `grep`'s output won't be written to the pipe until its input generates EOF, which won't happen until the `bin/Prog` exits.  So, until the program exits, the `grep` and the `tail` are stuck, and since you are waiting for `grep` and `tail` to exit before telling the program to exit, you have a deadlock.

You might do better with `tail -n +1` which looks for one line of output at the start (or `sed 1q` or `head -n 1` or …).  However, you're still stuck with `grep` buffering its output, which leaves you in a quandary.

Comment: Adding a bunch of "stdbuf -i0 -o0 -e0" to my script did not help. Is that consistent with what you said?

Comment: I'd not come across [`stdbuf`](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html) before.  I'm not sure I even see how it works; I would not have expected the buffering mode set by the initial process to affect the buffering of the process it executes. Given that, I'm not sure whether the behaviour you're seeing is consistent with this or not. I expect it is, but I'm frankly uncertain.